# How to edit digits inside a venn diagram in Rstudio

Tags: r, venn-diagram, gplots

I want to visualise true-positives and true-negatives using a venn diagram. Is it possible to edit the "digits" given inside the venn diagram?

I have made a normal venn diagram in R, using gplots. One of the circle has True-positive and True-negative findings, which is shown as the sum of these two in the circle. For example, if there is 1 True-Positive and 1 True-negative, the circle shows a digit "2". How can I show "1+1" in this circle(example; circle Mx)?

```
library(gplots)
L_1 <- c("A","B", "C","D")
L_2 <- c("C","D","E","F","G","H")
L_3 <- c("C","D","X","Y","Z")
list_all <- list(Mx=L_1,Cx=L_2,Kx=L_3)
venn(list_all)
```

I would like to see value in Mx as "1+1" instead of "2".

Comment: One thing to try, get the data from the `Venn` function using `x <- venn(list_all, show.plot = FALSE)` and then create a custom diagram using ggplot or similar.